# creating a simple list of hyperlinks in d3.js or JS

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, hyperlink

I have a string containing comma separated urls like this:

> "www.url1.com, www.url2.com, www.url3.com".

I am able to pass this string to a JS function. I can also break this string up into a list of urls. Beyond this how can I loop through this list and create a simple page of hyperlinks like below? I prefer a d3.js based solution.

```
<a href="www.url1.com">First URL!</a>
<a href="www.url1.com">Second URL!</a>
<a href="www.url1.com">Third URL!</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have marked down your example with a >.  Please edit you post and show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd like to do this with a library instead of plain js, easiest will be like

```js
    var str = "www.url1.com, www.url2.com, www.url3.com";
    str.split(',').forEach(function(url, i) {
        var el = document.createElement('a');
        el.href = "http://" + url.trim();
        el.innerHTML = "URL " + ++i
        document.body.appendChild(el); // or target div
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using d3.

```js
var str = "www.url1.com, www.url2.com, www.url3.com";

var urls = str.split(",");

var anchors = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("a")
  .data(urls)
  .enter()
  .append("a")
  .attr("href", function(url) {
    return url.trim();
  })
  .text(function(url, i) {
    return "URL " + (i + 1);
  });

anchors.insert("br",":first-child");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```